# Given a python 2.7.2 type is there anyway I can construct a class instance programmatically?

Tags: python, class, types, constructor, instance

```
class MType(type):
 pass

class MClass(object):
 __metaclass__ = MType

a = MType
```

From the above snippet is there anyway I can create an instance of `MClass` given `a`?

(It's probably important to note that I won't be able to simply contruct `MClass()`)

Comment: Are you assuming that you know what 'MClass' is (i.e. asking for it by name?) .. Or do you expect 'a' to be able to find it automatically? If so, do you care if it inherits from two classes?

Comment: No, don't necessarily know what MClass is. I was thinking maybe there'd be a way in python to get the class given a type. But then I guess there's no 1:1 relationship there anyway. No big deal, a thousand ways to skin a cat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two straightforward ways I can think of to find the instances of a metaclass.  One is to have the metaclass keep track of a list of its instances as they are created, as follows:

```
class MType(type):
    instances = []    #list of instances of the metaclass

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
            MType.instances.append(cls)    #append to list of instances
            super(MType, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)

class MClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = MType
```

Now `MType.instances` is `[<class '__main__.MClass'>]`.

Another way is to use the 
[inspect module](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) to look through the classes in, say, a given module, and use `isinstance` to check if they are instances of `MType`.  This isn't necessarily a crazy thing to do, either - for example, various unit testing suites work by looking through a module for classes and functions that appear to be tests, based on their names and/or inherited classes - I'm not really sure why you would want to do this with a metaclass, though.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a horrific way of doing it. Although, I'll be honest.. I'm not sure what the difference between setting `__metaclass__` as a module property is vs. inheritance.

```
class MType(type):
    pass

class MClass(MType):
    pass

a = MType

print a.__mro__[0].__subclasses__(a)
```

Yields:

```
[<class '__main__.MClass'>]
```

Comment: Just getting into it but I find python's flexibility fascinating. For the issue that prompted this question I just rearranged my module structure for greater clarity but thanks for making me aware of the MRO.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work with metaclasses, as in that case `MClass` is an instance of `MType` rather than a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you have `b = MClass`, you can simply do `obj = b()`, but the metaclass does not "know" about the class(es) it is set as the metaclass of.

You could call `__new__` on `a` if you have the class in a variable, whether `b` or `MClass`.